# Onsen Navigator.pushPage not working with Wordpress

Tags: angularjs, onsen-ui, navigator

I am trying to integrate Onsen Ui with WordPress, but when I click on the `myNavigator.pushPage` the expended post is not populated. What did I do wrong?

```
<ons-list-item myNavigator.pushPage ("# / blog / {{ post.categories[0].slug }} / {{ post.slug }}", options);>
```

Thanks,
Prem

Comment: If you want that working "on click", well, you need to specify `onclick="..."` or `ng-click="..."`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use ng-click or on-click.Use the following code: 
`<ons-list-item ng-click="myNavigator.pushPage('page.html',{option1: 1}, { animation : 'slide' } )"`>